# Get number of tweets of a user

Tags: php, twitter, count, tweets

Is there a way to get the total number of tweets from a Twitter user? I just want to display the number of tweets and I tried it like this but I always get just 0:

```
<?php
$twit = file_get_contents('http://twitter.com/users/show/matejlatin.xml');
$begin = '<statuses_count>'; $end = '</statuses_count>';
$page = $twit;
$parts = explode($begin,$page);
$page = $parts[1];
$parts = explode($end,$page);
$tcount = $parts[0];
if($tcount == '') { $tcount = '0'; } 
echo '<h3 id="tweets">'.$tcount.'</h3>';  
?>
```

Comment: That code works perfectly for me. Are you getting any errors (e.g. in your web server log)?

Comment: there's a lot going on in the log file but I don't see any errors.. not sure how to find them if they are, to be honest...

Comment: @matejilatin: if you're using a standard apache install, you should have a separate access log and error log.

Comment: Ok found it:

20120918T152954: matoweb.com/index.php 
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /hermes/waloraweb071/b2170/moo.matowebcom/wp-content/themes/matoweb/first_page.php on line 97 
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.xml?screen_name=matejlatin): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /hermes/waloraweb071/b2170/moo.matowebcom/wp-content/themes/matoweb/first_page.php on line 97

Comment: after some research I tried changing the allow_url_fopen to On but still doesn't work... I giving up on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Is the Twitter result (`$twit`) what you expect ? If the Twitter API returns you wrong results, you will not be able to display the right things.

However you had better use another endpoint. [Twitter will remove a lot of endpoints on 09/25/2012](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/10803) and your endpoint (`GET http://twitter.com/users/:user_name_or_id.xml`) is planned to be removed in 6 days since it is not on **api**.twitter.com and it does not contain the version number (`/1` for you I guess). Your bug might be due to this now **but in 6 days it will be one of its causes for sure**.

So change your endpoint for one of these :

- `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json` ([documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/show)). This is the endpoint used by the (controversial) 1.1 version of the API and it will be the only endpoint available in the future.
- `GET http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.format` ([documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show)). This endpoint will be removed in less than 6 months with the 1.0 version of the Twitter API.
- `GET http://api.twitter.com/1/users/:user_name_or_id.format` ([documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show)). This endpoint will be removed in less than 6 months with the 1.0 version of the Twitter API.

Comment: thanks, I'll take your answer in consideration and will change the endpoint as you suggested. But I don't think that's the actual problem here...